# Filter and sort swift array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uisearchbar

I have a swift array which I want to filter, here is the array

```
let array = [apple,workshops,shopping,sports,parties,pantry,pen]
```

I want to filter the array in such a way that the **items beginning with the search string to appear before items that just contain the search string**

So when i search for example p, then the results should be in some way

```
let array = [parties,pantry,pen,apple,workshops,shopping,sports]
```

I tried this

```
tagSearchResults = tagSearchResults.filter({ (interestTag:InterestTag) -> Bool in
            let tmp: NSString = interestTag.tag
            let range = tmp.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
            return range.location != NSNotFound
        })
```

but this gives me all strings containing the search string.

So guys how can i do this

Comment: What you're looking for can be done in two steps: filter first (as you are doing already) and then do a (custom) sort.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can just write

```
 let result = words
    .filter { $0.contains(keyword) }
    .sorted { ($0.hasPrefix(keyword) ? 0 : 1) < ($1.hasPrefix(keyword) ? 0 : 1) }
```

### Example

```
let words = ["apple", "workshops", "shopping", "sports", "parties", "pantry", "pen", "cat", "house"]
let keyword = "p"
let result = words
    .filter { $0.contains(keyword) }
    .sorted { ($0.hasPrefix(keyword) ? 0 : 1) < ($1.hasPrefix(keyword) ? 0 : 1) }

// ["pen", "pantry", "parties", "apple", "workshops", "shopping", "sports"]
```

Comment: This *might* work, but strictly speaking, the sort() method requires that the comparison method is a ["strict weak ordering"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_order#Strict_weak_orderings), and that is not the case here: It is not *irreflexive* (unless I am mistaken).

Comment: @MartinR: You are right `MartinR` and thank your for pointing it out. I just updated my code.

Comment: That should work now. One remark though: `Int(someBool)` does a `Bool -> NSNumber -> Int` conversion, which is not obvious and might be unexpected.

Comment: @MartinR: Ok, I replace the `Int(someBool)` with the ternary conditional operator. Thank you for sharing your observation! I really appreciate that.

Comment: And now you should test your code again. It does not print what you claim it does :)

Comment: Hey @appzYourLife, and martin thanks for the answer, but how can we optimize it, presently by keyboard hangs when i type

Comment: @Ranjit: You should run the filter logic on a separate thread in order to avoid blocking the main thread (where the UI is updated)

Comment: Swit array sorting filtering helper class - [click here](https://pratiksodha.medium.com/array-adapter-sorting-filtering-and-searching-709d9cc3f46a)

Answer (score 14):

Try this. Firstly, it filters the array to remove those elements that do not contain the search string, then uses a custom sort to prefer items that start with the search string. In general, use the Cartesian approach of splitting a problem into smaller sub-problems, rather than try to solve it all in one step.

```
let searchString = "p"
let array = ["apple", "workshops", "shopping", "sports", "parties", "pantry", "pen", "xyzzy"]

let filteredArray = array.filter({ $0.contains(searchString) })
filteredArray // drops xyzzy

let sortedArray = filteredArray.sorted(isOrderedBefore:  {
    switch ($0.hasPrefix(searchString), $1.hasPrefix(searchString)) {
    case (true, true):
        return $0 < $1
    case (true, false):
        return true
    case (false, true):
        return false
    case (false, false):
        return $0 < $1
    }

})
sortedArray // "pantry", "parties", "pen", "apple", "shopping", "sports", "workshops"] as required
```

Comment: I've misunderstood the question, this is the right answer.

Comment: This is a better answer than the accepted answer since it sorts the matching and non-matching items within their sub-groups. Well done. (Voted)

Comment: let sortedArray = filteredArray.sorted(isOrderedBefore:  {
    let a = $0.hasPrefix(searchString);
    return (a == $1.hasPrefix(searchString)) ? $0 < $1 : a
})

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

```
let searchString = "p"
let array = ["apple", "workshops", "shopping", "sports", "parties", "pantry", "pen", "xyzzy"]
let result = array.filter{$0.containsString(searchString)}
    .map{($0.hasPrefix(searchString) ? 0 : 1, $0)}
    .sort{$0 < $1}
    .map{$1}
print(result) //->["pantry", "parties", "pen", "apple", "shopping", "sports", "workshops"]
```

(I don't know why, but my Xcode took huge time to compile these lines. Believe this compiles and runs as expected eventually.)