# UITableView SearchBar filtering inquiry

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, filter, uisearchbar

I have a very long tableView that I am able to search and filter results.

However, if I were to type the letter "i" as input, 
all words with the letter "i" show up. 
Is it possible to filter in a way so that the letter I type corresponds to the first letter of the word I want to filter.

For example my array `["should not use","Tristan","biscuit","is","should not use"]`

and  if I search the word `"is"`

, can that word automatically show up before the word "biscuit"?

> Expected Result :
>   **["is","biscuit","Tristan"]**

Comment: I believe this is a very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38718005/filter-and-sort-swift-array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use filter and sorted function to get the expected result.

```
import UIKit

    var theArray: [String] = ["biscuit", "Tristan", "is", "iser", "instrument", "look"]
    var keyword: String = "is"

    let result = theArray
        .filter { $0.contains(keyword) }
        .sorted() { ($0.hasPrefix(keyword) ? 0 : 1) < ($1.hasPrefix(keyword) ? 0 : 1) }


    print(result)
```

**OUTPUT**

> ["is", "iser", "biscuit", "Tristan"]

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't this conditional on the value given for the keyword string?

Comment: you can replace keyword with your search-bar text

Comment: I see what you're saying but I'm questioning the efficiency of it. Can I search based on number of characters in a word?

Comment: what you mean i cant get your point can you elaborate it with example

Comment: I believe your answer is actually the correct method for what I want, but, I'm not sure how to incorporate it with the other code you helped me with to filer the array.

Comment: just apply sorted function on your filtered array i think you already get your filter array right problem is just with sorting

Comment: not really sure how to do that but I'll try to figure it out

Comment: Let me ask you this. Can I filter using both the $0.coptic.lowercased().contains(searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercased()) and $0.coptic.lowercased() == searchController.searchBar.text?.lowercased() and have it sort the latter filter first?

Comment: array.filter { $0.coptic.lowercased().contains(searchController.searchBar.t‌​ext!.lowercased())  || $0.coptic.lowercased() == searchController.searchBar.text?.lowercased() }

Comment: yes, I had already tried this. The problem I encountered was that if I searched an exact word that started with the letter "r", it wouldn't move up to the top of the list. So if for example I looked up "ray", it would filter back the word "array" before it.

Comment: I also tried it without the || operator to see what would happen and all it did would return the same word twice following each other.

Comment: have you sorted after filtering it

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to sort it. Because my tableView consists of words in a different language, it doesn't follow the standard English alphabet.

Comment: It's literally the same filter code you posted to the other question

Comment: in whcih array you want sort coptic or english

Comment: coptic. I'm trying to get the lowercased() == searchController result to show up at the top of the list and all the other words to appear underneath it

Comment: i think you can sort after for loop tempWord.coptic = copticArray.sorted()